# Can I use hashCode function of a class to verify if both has same value for areContentsTheSame in diffutils callback?

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-livedata, listadapter, android-diffutils

I am trying to implement RecyclerView ListAdapter with DiffUtils callback to only update/insert rows that has been changed not all. To implement I have to override these function from diff utils
`areItemsTheSame` and `areContentsTheSame`. I can check `areItemsTheSame` using id of each object which I get from db. But for `areContentsTheSame` I don't want to write equals function and match each and every field with `.equals` method or similiar. I am wondering can I use default hashCode function from the class? If not can I override hashCode function like this?

```java
public class Person {
  String name;
  String surname;
  String country;
  int age;    

  public Person(String name, String surname, String country, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.surname = surname;
      this.country = country;
      this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      int prime=31;
      int sum = prime*this.name.hashCode();
      sum=sum+this.surname.hashCode();
      sum=sum+this.country.hashCode();
      sum=sum+this.age;
      return sum;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) states the following:

> If two objects are equal according to the
>   equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>   two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> It is not required
>   that if two objects are unequal according to the
>   equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>   each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.

Therefore, only using `hashCode()` function to check equality can give wrong results, given the probability that produced integers for different objects may have the same value.

If your concern is about having a long `equals()` method where every field is compared, you can only compare the fields that matters for equality.